# django-multi-captcha-admin permission denied

Tags: python, django, recaptcha

I have a Django project up and running. I followed required steps for `django-recaptcha` and even used captcha v2 in my template. my problem is with the admin site captcha requiring. I tried to use `django-multi-captcha-admin` package. I followed the documentation steps ([this is the documentation](https://pypi.org/project/django-multi-captcha-admin/)) but the problem is when I try to login as admin I see this error:

[The admin page picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbnDA.png)

`You don’t have permission to view or edit anything.`

I searched and I didn't find anything on the internet so I asked ChatGPT and this was its answer:

> Make sure that the middleware of multi_captcha_admin is placed correctly in the MIDDLEWARE list, following the AuthenticationMiddleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
# ...
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'multi_captcha_admin.middleware.MultiCaptchaAdminMiddleware',
# ...
]
```

The new problem with this solution is when I add this part to my MIDDLEWARE I get this error trying to run server:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multi_captcha_admin.middleware'
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'haadijafari.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

Comment: Searching the [code and documentation](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aa-roomana%2Fdjango-multi-captcha-admin%20middleware&type=code) of django-multi-captcha-admin, it does not mention middleware anywhere. I doubt that's the issue.

Comment: I think its not the permission issue. I inspected the admin site and saw the captcha div is there. Is it possible for the captcha statics to not be loaded?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with previous `django-captcha-admin` which I installed for the same purpose. I think when I ran the command pip uninstall `django-captcha-admin` it didn't fully remove. I removed my `venv` and recreate it. I also installed the requirements file but this time with only `django-multi-captcha-admin`